# migrating from testing site to live site

Tags: css, html, url, dreamweaver

I've designed a site in dreamweaver with very simple and plain basic HTML. My problems are with my directories and urls when I want to go live.

Here is an example of a page on my testing server:

```
file:///C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/mysite/catering/cold-finger-food-platters.html
```

Now when I go live needles to say all my links and directories are invalid...

**What is the best approach to go from a testing site to a live site keeping urls / links /images correctly intact?**

**Update**

```
<img src="images/catering.png" alt="finger food catering for weddings"  />
```

Now I want to move this to a different directory. See where my problem comes in?

Comment: Use relative paths for all resources and this will not be a problem at all.

Comment: normally , when we upload our site , in to host server public folder. so , when you type your url it redirect to public folder in server. normally first load index.html file. ex : www.mydomain.com , mean www.mydomain.com\index. when you give redirect code to necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have to upload your external files too. Post your HTML file (the code) and I will tell you what to upload into the folders they belong in.

Comment: Also, if you are still working on your site, don't use Wordpress, use 000webhost. It's free for ever until you decide you want to pay and you can do what ever you want.

Comment: Okay, still do what I said to in the answer and it will work perfectly.

Comment: ya,use ooowebhost   , it has good  for beginners learn about web hosting.

Comment: Mate please dont promote services on here

Comment: WTF has free webhosting got to do with the problem??? You might aswell say go to godaddy they can help you

Comment: You know, in the few months I've been on here, I haven't seen anyone who's autistic besides you. I'm out kid cya

Comment: Says the one with a reputation of 6...Please explain to me how ooowebhost is going to help me?

Comment: Because you need to learn how to code, not have a shitty paid company like Wordpress do it for you. Grow a pair and be a man

Comment: What the f***has coding got to do with it, it is not even a bloody coding question?

Comment: Are you from Australia?

Comment: Does the answer to the question matter where I am from...Look I dont usually do this type of work...Hench im asking for help...and you tell me go to free webhosting ooola to solve the problem???